# {"error":{"code":"RESTAPINotEnabledForComponentSharedMailbox","message":"REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox."}}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365api

I dont know where to post this, so im posting it here.

So Im trying out the Office 365 API. I've been following a tutorial : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/authenticate-and-use-services

I downloaded the sample from: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-SingleTenant

I believe ive set everything up correctly as it compiles, runs and Im able to login - However when I click on the "My Contact" link, I get this error:

> {"error":{"code":"RESTAPINotEnabledForComponentSharedMailbox","message":"REST
>   API is not yet supported for this mailbox."}}

Has anyone had any experience using this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the user doesn't have the mailbox in EXO cloud. Can you verify where the users mailbox is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for my ignorance, but what does EXO cloud have to do with Microsoft ? The email address I am using is the Global Administrator within Azure Active Directory.

Comment: EXO is O365 Exchange Online Cloud. So if you don't have mailbox in the cloud O365 Exchange REST APIs will not work for these users.